# Python3 importing classes

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn python and I thought a good way to practice would be by building a custom linked list class. I was able to get my custom list to work properly when everything was in one file. However, I wanted to practice importing, so I split my code into three files: ListNode.py, mySLL.py, testMySll.py. All of these files are under the same directory "codingPractice". I'm trying to import listNode.py into mySLL.py and mySLL.py into testMySll.py. How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `import listNode`?

Comment: Ended up doing from listNode import ListNode to actually use the ListNode class I made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing modules in Python is pretty straight forward. For a thorough explanation see this [guide on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). However, to give you a quickstart using the examples you provided, you can import modules like this:

```
    # importing into mySLL.py
    import listNode

    bar = listNode.func(foo)
```

The same workflow goes for importing mySSL.py into the testMySll.py file. Keep in mind that imported modules act like objects so you call the functions using `module.func` and any variables that are global in the module can be called using `module.var`.

Comment: Ended up doing from listNode import ListNode to actually use the ListNode class I made